# I am using dataset in vs 2012 but view tableadapter not ganerate code in designer.cs

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, dataset, view

I am create database in sql2008 include tables and views.
using data set for working sql in vs 2012.
I am drag table to data set code generate table adapter.but draging veiws in data set does not generate Code tableadapter

Answer (score 0):

If the TableAdapter is not being generated automatically, have you tried right-clicking the DataSet background and selecting Add new/Table Adapter?

Comment: tnk.but for the method right-clicking the DataSet background and selecting Add new/Table Adapter add existing view not generate automatically code...

Comment: Can you confirm what is actually generated when you perform this action?  Not sure we have enough information to go on!  A screenshot would be handy.